# When can I use `Shift` + `Alt` + `mouse left click` shortcut in Photoshop brush mode

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm using Adobe photoshop 2020, and I wonder about this shortcut.

Brush mode and <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + click,

and I can pick some color. But I don't know How I use picked color.

[image]

How can I use this shortcut?

Answer (score 2):

With a Brush active...

- Holding down the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key and clicking picks up the color under the click and assigns it as the **foreground** **color**.
- Holding down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> keys and clicking adds a **color target** to the image.

*How* you use this is up to you.

If you simply want to paint with a color, use the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key and forget about the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key. If you pick up a color by holing <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> and clicking, loading it as the **foreground** color, you can then immediately paint with that color.

If you want **color targets**, you can place them and then view the data in the **Info Panel** (`Window > Info`) for the targets. Color targets are used to view color values at specific areas of an image. Often useful for color correction. Color targets do **not** "pick up" or otherwise load any color for use in painting. In fact, color targets have no "painting" ability. They are for information purposes only.